# Cannot Upload Custom Header Image into Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble uploading a custom image into Wordpress' dashboard. It says that it needs to be a custom 1000x288 image. When I upload it, I get the error of:

```
Warning: copy(/var/sites/zeldezine/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/header.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/sites/zeldezine/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 348


Warning: getimagesize(/var/sites/zeldezine/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/header.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/sites/zeldezine/wordpress/wp-admin/custom-header.php on line 665
```

When I open /includes/file.php, I get this block of code on line 348

```
// Set correct file permissions
    $stat = stat( dirname( $new_file ));
    $perms = $stat['mode'] & 0000666;
    @ chmod( $new_file, $perms );
```

but I am not experienced enough in PHP to be able to know how to set the permissions correctly. If anyone can give me a heads up on what I need to modify to set permissions correctly, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have write access to your wordpress installation directory?

Comment: @mrtsherman: Yes

Comment: @MattZelenak are you sure? :) What are the file permissions on `/uploads`... as a test, set the permissions on `/var/sites/zeldezine/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/` to 0777 and see if it works.

Comment: @Ben D: Many thanks! Works perfectly. So what was I doing wrong? It was already set to 777, but I added the 'write' permission to group & other.

Comment: You should make sure that 777, write permission is set directly on the uploads folder... as you can see, Wordpress will generate sub folders based on year/month

Comment: @MattZelenak Jeffrey's right on this (making sure that the parent directory is 777). As for why it worked, 777 means "all permissions to owner","all permissions to group", and "all permissions to everyone else". This means that unless the uid that PHP uses is set as the owner, you have to allow it to access as either part of the group or as just any random service.

Comment: **WHY WAS THIS QUESTION MIGRATED HERE?!?**. This is a *user-support* question, that should be directed to the [official wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support), and not *here*, because it is outside the scope of WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

Please Give the permission to Folder uploads to 755 and its subfolders.

Answer (score -1):

whenever you upload something , wordpress will automatically generate sub-folders inside 'uploads' based on the current date (year and month) , so avoid being stupid and keep modifying the permission of each folder generated inside uploads directory, 
rather set the permissions of the uploads folder to '755', it will automatically applied to its sub-directories.

Comment: It is not advisable to set ANY part of the WordPress directory/file structure to world-writable. The [Codex recommends 755](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions).